# How to read one observation per header record in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have the following data file

```
H 321 s main st
P mary e      21 f
P aby e       23 m
P stary e     31 f
P dory e      23 m
H 321 s second st
P lary e      31 m
P laby e      43 m
P ltary e     31 m
P lory e      23 m
P lwey e      43 f
P lwty e      35 f
P lowtetr e   25 m
H 4351 s 35343nd st
```

---

I try to calculate the number of people living at a certain address . So the resulting data set should have 3 observations .

Here is the code

```
data ch21.test2 ; 
    infile testFile   end = last ;
    retain address ; 

    input  type $1.  @   ;
            if type = 'H' then   
                do ; 
                if _n_ > 1 then 
                output ; 
                total=0 ; 
                input @3 address $3-21 ;        
                end ;
            else if type='P' then 
                input @3 name $12. +1 age 2. +1 gender $1.   ;   
                total+1  ; 
                if last then
                output ; 
    run ;
```

However i get only one row .

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are missing `&`. You data contains blanks . Try this

```
data ch21.test2 ; 
    infile testFile   end = last ;
    retain address ; 

    input  type $1.  @   ;
            if type = 'H' then   
                do ; 
                if _n_ > 1 then 
                output ; 
                total=0 ; 
                input @3 address & $18. ;     /*  ADDED &  and corrected to $18. */   
                end ;
            else if type='P' then 
                input @3 name & $12. +1 age 2. +1 gender $1.   ;    /* ADDED & */
                total+1  ; 
                if last then
                output ; 
    run ;
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  He is not trying to use list input; in particular, once you converted it correctly to formatted input, the `&` does not do anything anymore.  The code above has several problems, which are not fixed by this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you only got one row out of your code; I get two when I run it (probably three, I'm using `datalines` which do not support the `end` variable).  However, you don't have a `do` loop around the `else` condition, which leads to you getting the wrong answer (probably one higher than you should).  Your input is a bit confusing as it combines input styles, but it's not wrong particularly; I changed it below to what I'm more comfortable with but yours works as well (it's just harder to read).  I did however add a @1 to `type` that is probably a good idea; in the event that you have unexpected input issues, @1 makes sure you're reading the first character (as that's what you want).

If you're still only getting one row, you may have an issue with the format of your data file; perhaps it is a UNIX file and you're reading on a Windows machine, so it doesn't respect the EOL character, for example.

```
data test2 ; 
infile datalines   end = last ;
retain address ; 

input  @1 type $1.  @   ;  *add @1;
        if type = 'H' then   
         do ; 
            if _n_ > 1 then 
            output ; 
            total=0 ; 
            input @3 address $19. ; *converted to formatted style;
         end ;
        else if type='P' then do;  *added do - you had indented here but did not have a do;
            input @3 name $12. @15 age 2. @18 gender $1.; *converted to all formatted style;
            total+1  ; 
        end;                       *added end - assuming if last then output should be outside?;
        if last then
            output ; 
datalines;
H 321 s main st
P mary e      21 f
P aby e       23 m
P stary e     31 f
P dory e      23 m
H 321 s second st
P lary e      31 m
P laby e      43 m
P ltary e     31 m
P lory e      23 m
P lwey e      43 f
P lwty e      35 f
P lowtetr e   25 m
H 4351 s 35343nd st 
;;;;
run;
```